# Swashbuckle breaks when upgrading from 5.3.2 to 5.6.0

Tags: .net, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

After upgrading from Swashbuckle 5.3.2 to 5.6.0, I now get the following error when going to `http://localhost:567/swagger/ui/lib/handlebars-2-0-0-js`:

```
<Error>
  <Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
  <ExceptionMessage>Mapping not found - lib/handlebars-2-0-0-js</ExceptionMessage>
  <ExceptionType>Swashbuckle.SwaggerUi.AssetNotFound</ExceptionType>
  <StackTrace>
    at Swashbuckle.SwaggerUi.EmbeddedAssetProvider.GetAsset(String rootUrl, String path) at Swashbuckle.Application.SwaggerUiHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  </StackTrace>
</Error>
```

Absolutely no other code has changed.  If I revert the change, it works again.  Any ideas on what changed that would break this?

Here's the only configuration I have:

```
.EnableSwagger(c =>
    {
        string rootUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(Constants.SwaggerRootUrl);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rootUrl)) {
            c.RootUrl(req => rootUrl);
        }

        string tosMsg = "...";
        c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "Web API")
            .Description("Warning: This site is for authorized partners only. " + tosMsg);

        c.OAuth2("oauth2")
            .Description("OAuth2 Implicit Grant")
            .Flow("implicit")
            .AuthorizationUrl(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(Constants.SwaggerOAuthBaseUrl) + "/connect/authorize")
            .Scopes(scopes =>
            {   
                scopes.Add("apiaccess", "Play with all the apis.");
            });

        c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
        c.OperationFilter<AssignOAuth2SecurityRequirements>();
        c.DocumentFilter<FilterByConsumer>();
        c.ResolveConflictingActions(apiDescriptions => apiDescriptions.First());
    })
```

Comment: that is strange there should not be any direct call to `swagger/ui/lib/handlebars-2-0-0-js` can you share a link to your broken implementation

Comment: We definitely can't publish anything broken, so I can only repro this on my local dev machine.  The Swagger UI page is simply blank (nav menu, with all white page).  Looking at the "view source" though, I see that everything it tries to load has that error where the old version does not..

Comment: on the old version do you see a call to that: `ui/lib/handlebars-2-0-0-js` ?

Comment: It should be loading just the bundle: `/swagger/ui/swagger-ui-bundle-js`

Comment: And out of curiosity why are you updating to 5.6.0? ... that is very old July 2017: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/releases/tag/v5.6.0  Maybe you should look into `swagger-net`, I started that as a fork of Swashbuckle but ended up detaching and transition it to own project: https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net

Comment: I was trying to install a package called `Swashbuckle.Examples` which had a requirement on 5.6.0.  I gave up trying to get it to work, and instead installed an older version of `Swashbuckle.Examples` which worked with the currently installed Swashbuckle.  I'll check out your project!

Comment: I see ... so your question is 2 layers deep. maybe post the actual need for that examples